# R not picking up user library

Tags: r, linux

I have a Fedora 30 system with R 3.6.0 and the user library is set in `Renviron` as this one:

```
R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6'}
```

And indeed it shows up in an interactive R session:

```
> Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER')
[1] "~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6"

> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/mu/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                          
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"     

> .Library
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library"

> .Library.site
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"
```

But then I also have a Debian 10 system where in the `/etc/Renviron` I have pretty much exactly the same line:

```
R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5'}
```

But it does not show up on my library search path, though the environment variable is there:

```
> Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER')
[1] "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5"

> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           

> .Library
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library"

> .Library.site
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

When I install packages it also suggests to install into that library, but then it does not find them and crashes, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647120/r-cran-package-installation-failing). What is missing for this directory to also make it into the library path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `~/.Renviron`, it might overwrite things. And if you have a `~/.Rprofile` which does a call to `.libPaths` with a non-existant directory you will have neither of them in your search path.